# How to load images in libGDX?

Tags: java, image, libgdx

I'm trying to make a game in java using libGDX. Right now the base is just Asteroids, so I followed a tutorial to create a basic replica of the original Asteroids game, complete with highscores. Unfortunately, both to draw the Asteroids and the ship, the creator of the tutorial drew the lines using geometric calculations, as opposed to using images. I'm wondering, how do I load actual pixel art in place of the lineart?

I've looked beyond page 2 on Google, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/A-simple-game#loading-the-assets

Answer (score 0):

This simple test:

`Copy` your file *.png for example, inside of the folder proyect Android, folder Assets.

```
AndroidProyectFolder-->AssetsFolder-->YourFile.png
```

**Variable class:**

```
Texture texture1;
SpriteBatch batch;
```

**Method Show or Create:**

```
texture1 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("YourFile.png"));
batch = new SpriteBatch();
```

**Method Render:**

```
.//
batch.begin();
batch.draw(texture1, 550, 380); //550 is X and 380 is Y position.
batch.end();
```

**P:S:** Try drawing all images within the same call to batch.begin as possible and not use batch begin, end, for each of the images you want to draw.

Comment: This got me somewhere, but I'm experiencing 2 problems. 1) the image no longer moves and 2) I used Texture.setEnforcePotImages(false); to stop getting the "Texture width and height must be powers of two" error. For some reason, now I just have a white block.